# ">" is not matched by "[[:punct:]]" when using `stringr::str_replace_all`?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I find this really odd :

```
pattern <- "[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]]+"
string  <- "a . , > 1 b"

gsub(pattern, " ", string)
# [1] "a b"

library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string, pattern, " ")
# [1] "a > b"

str_replace_all(string, "[[:punct:][:digit:][:space:]>]+", " ")
# [1] "a b"
```

Is this expected ?

Comment: Interesting. Might be a bug...?

Comment: See https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/248

Comment: It is not a bug, this is a known difference between POSIX character class implementation in TRE and ICU regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still working on this, but `?"stringi-search-charclass"` says:

> Beware of using POSIX character classes, e.g. ‘[:punct:]’. ICU
>        User Guide (see below) states that in general they are not
>        well-defined, so may end up with something different than you
>        expect.
>
> In particular, in POSIX-like regex engines, ‘[:punct:]’ stands for
>        the character class corresponding to the ‘ispunct()’
>        classification function (check out ‘man 3 ispunct’ on UNIX-like
>        systems). According to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (ISO C90), the
>        ‘ispunct()’ function tests for any printing character except for
>        space or a character for which ‘isalnum()’ is true. However, in a
>        POSIX setting, the details of what characters belong into which
>        class depend on the current locale. So the ‘[:punct:]’ class does
>        not lead to portable code (again, in POSIX-like regex engines).
>
> So a POSIX flavor of ‘[:punct:]’ is more like ‘[\p{P}\p{S}]’ in
>        ‘ICU’. You have been warned.

Copying from the issue posted above,

```
string  <- "a . , > 1 b"
mypunct <- "[[\\p{P}][\\p{S}]]" 
stringr::str_remove_all(string, mypunct)
```

I can appreciate stuff being locale-specific, but it still surprises me that `[:punct:]` doesn't even work in a C locale ...

Comment: thanks, so to be safe I'm using `str_replace_all(string, "[[\\p{P}][\\p{S}]\\d\\s]+"," ")` , and from '?stringi::``stringi-search-regex``' I get `\p{UNICODE PROPERTY NAME} : Match any character with the specified Unicode Property.` and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property teaches me that `P` is for punctuation and `S` is for symbols.

Comment: `So a POSIX flavor of ‘[:punct:]’ is more like ‘[\p{P}\p{S}]’ in ‘ICU’`, so important to note that they are still not equivalent, for instance the `€`& `$` symbols are removed by `mypunct` using `str_replace_all`, but not by `gsub` with `[:punct:]`